# PyCharm module importing stopped working properly (OS X)

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I've been working on a Django project for months, all has been fine, then I did a big code merge and PyCharm has stopped recognizing module imports. The following work:

```
from django.utils.timezone import *
from django.test.testcases import TransactionTestCase
from kimsim_app.views import *
```

But these no longer do:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
from kimsim_app import views
```

By work, I mean the latter `timezone` and `TransactionTestCase` are highlighted with red underlining. Lines of code that are missing imports are not underlined (although perhaps the parser gives up). Optimize imports does nothing. Update: a few minutes later and `testcases import TransactionTestCase` is again highlighted in red (edit - working again).

I have restored an old `.idea` directory from before the problems. I have recreated from scratch the virtual environment. I have duplicated the source, removed `.idea` and recreated the PyCharm project - nothing seem to help, yet running the Django unit tests from the command line work fine. When I navigate to the source of `django/utils/__init__.py` the code is not syntax highlighted. I have tried setting the settings file in Run Configurations and 'Settings, Languages and Frameworks, Django'. I have tried upgrading to PyCharm Pro 5.0.4. A colleague with identical source code has no problems.

Comment: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart` usually helps with messed-up code hints in correct files.

Comment: Thanks this was a potential answer rather than a comment - I wasn't aware of that function - but unfortunately didn't work in my case.

Comment: I've logged a bug with jetbrains [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18540)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when I uninstalled, deleted all the directories listed on [this page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) and below, then reinstalled, did the import validation start working again. On this latter attempt I did recreate the PyCharm project (ie, the .idea directory), I did not enter my license code for fear of it downloading saved settings or something, I did not recreate the virtual environment or VCS settings.

The directories listed for OS X:

Configuration: `~/Library/Preferences/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

Caches: `~/Library/Caches/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

Plugins: `~/Library/Application Support/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

Logs: `~/Library/Logs/<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

For Unix systems (I'm not sure if this bug affects Unix or Windows): `~/.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

Windows Vista, 7, 8: `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>` eg, `c:\Users\Bert\.PyCharm45\`

Windows XP: `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Documents and Settings\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`

In addition to the above, I also tried uninstalling all versions of PyCharm then reinstalling, creating new everything (virtual env, `.idea` project settings, etc) except the source code, but I still got the error - only when I deleted all the directories listed did the bug disappear. I haven't dared re-import my settings. The [jetbrains bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18540) hasn't been assigned after two days.